# Usage of "As a matter of common sense"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, punctuation

Is "as a matter of common sense" used correctly in the following sentence?

> Education is of immense value even for labor work, but some hiring employers ***as a matter of common sense*** value experience over education.

I wanted to mention that some employers tend to place a higher value on experience. They believe that experience is clearly more important that education. It is obvious and they think that no scientific evidence is needed to support their view.

Please tell me if it needs any punctuation. Should I place "as a matter of common sense" between commas?

Comment: Why the addition of "as a matter of common sense", though?

Answer (score 1):

Your usage is correct and I would leave it unchanged (but without the bold italics, of course).  Stylistically it is slightly worse to put in commas, to me.  I think after what you have, my next choice would be

> Education is of immense value even for labor work, but still some hiring employers value experience over education, simply as a matter of common sense.